# Image not displayed in vf page when rendered as pdf

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want an image in a vf page which is rendered as pdf. Below is the code

## VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="VFcontroller" renderAs="pdf" >
   <div style="border: 1px ridge gray; min-height: 150px; ">
       <div style="margin: 0 0 0 0">
          <apex:image value="{!componentImage }" width="200" height="220"/>
          <!-- <apex:outputText value="{!componentImage }" escape="false" /> -->
       </div>
   </div>
</apex:page>
```

## VF Controller

```
 public without sharing class VFcontroller{
     public String componentImage {get; set;}

     public VFcontroller(){
        oppId = Id.valueOf('0068E000007LAGZ'); // Dummy Oppty 
        Opportunity opty = [SELECT Id, chart__c  FROM 
                            Opportunity Where Id = :oppId]; //chart__c is a  Rich Text field with image stored in Base64 encoded string
        componentImage = opty.chart__c;
     }
 }
```

While rendered as PDF, I am getting the error image. If pdf not rendered, it is coming correct. How can I make it work with the pdf being rendered ?

Comment: The PDF renderer support is quite limited and I don't believe the approach you are taking is possible. Can you try store the encoded image as an attachment on the record and then use that?

Comment: I have experienced this error when trying to render an external image. If you go to Setup > Remote Site Settings and allow the endpoint where the image is hosted, you will see the image in the PDF.

Comment: @TSmith Thanks.. Makes sense.. But I don't want the users to see that particular attachment on the record. Is there a way I can control the visibility of the attachment?

Comment: @BijilRavindran you can modify the page layout to removed the Notes & Attachments related list.